# Получение cookies при запросе на Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookie, socket.io

Всем привет.

У клиента есть куки с флагом **httpOnly**
Есть модуль для **nodejs** **socket.io**,  как получить куки клиента при эмите на сокет?

Comment: Убрать флаг для начала?)

Comment: у большинства сайтов он с этим флагом, вот думаю как они реализовали

Comment: У большинства сайтов этот флаг установлен чтоб ваши шаловливые ручки не могли утащить их куки при помощи js ;)

Comment: А вдруг и до моего сайта дойдут шаловливые ручки?

Comment: Логично что в таком случае вы откроете уязвимость но тут вам выбирать нужны ли вам сокеты или нет... и да кто вам мешает использовать разные куки для сокета и для http?) И у одной из них не ставить httponly?)))

Comment: сгенерировать ещё 1 jwp и запихать с названием DlyaSocketIO, а потом его отправлять при запросе к сокету что бы сокет был вместе с аудентификацией. Идея хорошая, но я думал это костыль

Comment: Если содержимое куки разное - это безопасность а не костыль, т.е. одна кука позволяет только через сокет работать, вторая только через http :)

Comment: я понял что безопасно, но не костыль ли это?

Answer (score 0):

Создать JWT куку при авторизации, и отправлять её при запросе к нужному сокету, после чего помечать сокет ассоциацией, и проверять ассоциацию при эмите сокета